# RBAC for integration accounts in logic apps is not available

Tags: powershell, azure, rbac, azure-logic-apps

In the portal, I can see an error message when a user with read permission at the integration account level try to upload something in the integration account it says user doesn't have

> Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/schemas/write permission.

But, while creating custom RBAC when I enter the same permission and try to create RBAC (in both powershell as well as REST API) am getting error message

> "InvalidActionOrNotAction: The role definition includes an invalid
>   Action or NotAction."

also the command `Get-AzureRMProviderOperation Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/*` reveals nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now this is not supported. However, this is in pipeline and will be addressed.

Thank you,
Raj